# Why does the %m format specifier for printf output "Success"?

Tags: c

How is the output of this code is "Success"?  When I compiled this code it simply outputs "Success"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%m");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Glibc extension to `printf`.  It outputs the result of `strerror(errno)` and requires no argument.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

```
   m      (Glibc  extension.)   Print output of strerror(errno).  No argu-
          ment is required.
```

Since `errno` starts out at 0 on startup, it prints the message for error code 0, which is `Success`.